# Not able to generate signed apk

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-2.2

No matter what I do, when I try to generate a signed APK, this is what it shows me every time:

[image]

Tried to uninstall android studio and reinstall it, but the same story.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: this image shows no error

Comment: I've edited your question, but you could have simply dragged and dropped the picture from your pc..

Comment: @RahulKumar it is not showing me the edit fields for entering keystore password.

Comment: @Mansuro will do it from next time :)

Comment: @SaikiranBait what happens when you click on any buttons in the dialogs?